# want a better bound the expression

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Consider the expression 
$$
  f_n(x)=\sum_{d|n,1<d\leq x} \Lambda(d)\left(\frac{1}{\log d}-\frac{1}{\log x}\right)
$$

I've got $f_n(x)=\operatorname{O}\left(\frac{ x}{(\log x)^2}\right)$, but I've not used the fact $d|n$. I've got that just running $d$ from $2$ to $x$. Can we get a better bound ?

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $|f_n(x)|=O(\log (n+1))$, where the implied constant is absolute.

Firstly observe that $$\int_{d}^x\left(\frac{1}{\log u}\right)'\mathrm{d}u=
\frac{1}{\log x}-\frac{1}{\log u}.$$
We therefore obtain the representation $$f_n(x)=\int_1^x \left(\frac{1}{\log u}\right)'\left(\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ 1<d\leq u}}\Lambda(d)\right)\mathrm{d}u,$$ which shows via the use of $\sum_{d|n}\Lambda(d)=\log n$ that $$f_n(x)\ll \log\left(n+1\right) \int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)'\mathrm{d}x\ll \log (n+1).$$

Comment: that bound is of no use for my problem. It would be perfect if i get something like $O(\frac{x^{c}}{(\log x)^2})$ for some c<1

Comment: You have to specify a few more details, namely what is the range for $x$ in relation to $n$ that you are interested in ? Is it for fixed $n$ and as $x$ goes to infinity or do you care about small values of $x$ as well ? Also do you consider $n$ fixed or you don't care about the dependence of the error term in $n$ ?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because if $x$ is very small compared to $n$ then the bound $O(x(\log x)^{-2})$ is best possible and here is why: Assume that $n:=\prod_{p\leq x}p$. Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes below $x$ and $\theta(x)$ be the sum of logarithms of all primes below $x$. Then $f_n(x)=\pi(x)-\frac{\theta(x)}{\log x}\gg \frac{x}{(\log x)^2},$ where the last inequality follows from the prime number theorem in the form $\psi(x)=Li(x)+O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^3})$. I thought you were aware of this example which is why I tried to give a bound independent of $x$ in my answer above.